# How to enable autocomplete when using Internet Explorer and SSL?

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl, autocomplete

When both of the following conditions are true:

```
1.The page was delivered over HTTPS

2.The page was delivered with headers or a META tag that prevents caching
```

...the Autocomplete feature is disabled, regardless of the existence or value of the Autocomplete attribute. This remark applies to IE5, IE6, IE7, and IE8. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533486(VS.85).aspx

How can I override IEs default behavior given the scenario above?

An option is to use a different browser since this behavior only occurs in IE. However, changing browsers would be a major pain and my users prefer to stick with IE. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364066/why-is-the-internet-explorer-autocomplete-feature-disabled-for-all-html-forms-on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our goal with using the "no-cache" directive was to prevent forms from being submitted more than once. The unexpected consequence was that autocomplete stopped working. We discovered that changing to (Response.CacheControl = "must-revalidate, private") allows us to use autocomplete once again while using SSL. Hope this helps someone else.