# IE form autocomplete not working for HTTPS sites but works for HTTP site

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, https, autocomplete

We have long input form on ASP.NET site that was working fine with autocomplete feature of IE. but recently we changed site to use HTTPS protocol, after the change auto complete no more shows any suggestion. but if i switch back to HTTP it works. how can i enable auto complete for form with HTTPS. i have tried adding autocomplete="on" attribute without any luck.

Comment: possibly similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240695/how-to-enable-autocomplete-when-using-internet-explorer-and-ssl

Comment: i tried to do that in postback event as Response.cachecontrol = "must-revalidate" but did not work.

Comment: Is the Ajax call hitting https domain? Is it hard-coded to http?

Comment: there is no Ajax involved. this is just a webform with Asp.net controls and a asp.net button to submit form. the autocomplete that I am trying to use is IE inbuilt autocomplete.