# Auto complete in IE is not working for my webpage

Tags: php, internet-explorer, autocomplete, html

I have an official web page which is SSL certified. While opening this web page in my browser auto complete option is not working.

Even it is not asking "Do you want to save password for this site?".

But when i access other web page, browser is asking auto complete option.

What is the reason for it?

Comment: Usually the browser saves your password when the input type is 'username' and 'password', and you click on a submit button.

Comment: Did you try explicitly enabling autocomplete for [input](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp) or [form](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_form_autocomplete.asp)?

Comment: Also, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364066/why-is-the-internet-explorer-autocomplete-feature-disabled-for-all-html-forms-on) might be related.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: if both of the following conditions are true:

1. The page was delivered over HTTPS
2. The page was delivered with headers or a META tag that prevents caching

> The Autocomplete feature will be disabled, regardless of the existence or 
>   value of the Autocomplete attribute.

So if you're serving a page over ssl, you'll need to modify the Cache-control headers your server is sending to private, must-revalidate to allow IE autocomplete to work on these pages.

For more information, You can refer the answer in thread below.

[Form autocompletion not working](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/form-autocompletion-not-working)